# Get files modified or added yesterday from SharePoint document library

Tags: document-library, csom, caml-query, caml

I am trying to get all the files which is modified or added yesterday from SharePoint document library using below code.

```
            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
            clientContext.Load(list);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml =
                "<View Scope='Recursive'>"
                 + "  <Query>"
                 + "    <Where>"
                 + "<Geq>"
                 + "<FieldRef Name='Modified' />"
                 + "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='False'>"
                 + "<Today OffsetDays='" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("OffsetDays") + "' />"
                 + "</Value>"
                 + "</Geq>"
                 + "    </Where>"
                 + "  </Query>"
                 + "</View>";

            ListItemCollection listCol = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
            clientContext.Load(listCol);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            int cnt = listCol.Count;
            foreach (var item in listCol)
            {
                      TestingFiles(clientContext, item.FieldValues["FileDirRef"].ToString());
            }
```

Please note that the value of OffsetDays is -1.
But with the above code I am getting all the files instead only yesterdays files. Any idea what went wrong in my code.

Comment: I'm not able to read the CAML query, and that's probably where the issue is.

Comment: Hi Martijin, Can you please check now.

Comment: At least it's readable, but I don't have a solution for you. There are CAML query builder tools available, maybe that helps? Otherwise I've found that adding or removing the <View> tags makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks Martijin, CAML query builder tool(CAMLDESIGNER 2013) does not have option to query inside the folder with date criteria. View tag cant be remove since I need the recursive.

Comment: any progress on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing `<Geq></Geq>` with `<Eq></Eq>`. Based on my interpretation of your situation, that is what you need to change.

Comment: Hi James, what needs to be replaced? can you please explain.

Comment: Hi Sorry, i was on my way home and i forgot the code tag so it got stripped out. Please see updated answer

Comment: Hi James, I replaced <Geq></Geq> with <Eq></Eq> but still it fetching all the files. I guess recursive causing the issue. Without recursive how do i get all the files from folders and subfolders.